# how to deploy charm to a machine which is already installed with some other charm?

Tags: juju, maas

Is it like we have release  machine in maas then just do jitsu deploy-to "machine name" "service name" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Juju-Jitsu project is at this point depracated. The project is essentially un-maintained and doesn't work with juju-core (juju > 1.0). However, if you're using juju-core, you can use the `--force-machine` options during deploy to point the service to a machine. In the coming months support for containerization will land allowing you to more safely co-locate services on the same machine.

```
juju deploy --force-machine 0 wordpress
```

If you're using juju 0.7 still, you can use jitsu to co-locate services using the following syntax

```
jitsu deploy-to 0 wordpress
```

In both examples `0` is the machine number you're trying to deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy several charm on the same machine with jitsu depoy-to indeed.

The first argument is not the machine name though, it's the machine id.

You can get the machine id in the output of juju status: it start with all the machine in the "machines" section. It contain aussi the id of the machine each unit runs on (the integer next to the "machine: " line).

Comment: but in order to deploy new charm , i will need to release machine with is already installed with some other charm right?  Coz in order to install new charm i will need to have maas machine in "reday" state

Comment: No, you an jitsu deploy-to on an allocated machine (that s the whole point of it). As marco is saying in the above answer, if you are using juju-core, things will be different.